# Conditional matching

Tags: r, matching

I have two variables. I want to see if they one variable is in the other. Based on this match I want return a value from the same dataset that is associated with the row of that match into a new variable.  The condition is that if it doesn't match I want to use the value of one of the variables.

```r
df
Name              Name1             Name2 
Natalie             Shawn              Edmund
Desmond             Desmond            James
Kylie               Kylie             Brent
```

Desired output

```r
 df
Name          Name1             Name2            Fullname
Natalie     Shawn              Edmund            Natalie
Desmond     Desmond            Desmond James     Desmond James
Kylie       Kylie            Kylie Brent        Kylie Brent
```

I've tried:

```r
df$Fullname <- (df$Name2[match(df$Name, df$Name1)])
```

This gives me the full name  variable (i.e. Desmond James and Kylie Brent). Where I'm struggling is the conditional part and return a value when the variables don't match.  I've considered doing an ifelse nested coding but I'd like to stay from that as my dataset is rather large.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a condition with `ifelse` (assuming the columns are `character` class)

```
df$Fullname <- with(df, ifelse(Name == Name1 & !is.na(Name), 
                     paste(Name, Name2), Name))
df$Fullname
#[1] "Natalie"       "Desmond James" "Kylie Brent"
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(Fullname = case_when(Name == Name1 ~ str_c(Name, Name), TRUE ~ Name))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Natalie", "Desmond", "Kylie"), Name1 = c("Shawn", 
"Desmond", "Kylie"), Name2 = c("Edmund", "James", "Brent")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it partially works.I tried it on my full dataset but unfortunately, instead of printing the « Name » variable in the false condition, I get an NA instead. it works however when the condition is true!

Comment: @Dr.E77  May be you have `NA` in your datasets.  This is based on the example you showed and it is workiing for me

Comment: I do have NAs. How should I handle these first? Essentially they are blank responses from respondents.

Comment: @Dr.E77  IN that case, do `with(df, ifelse(Name == Name1 & !is.na(Name), paste(Name, Name2), Name))`

Comment: @Dr.E77  Can you try that

Comment: Brilliant! That did it. As a rule of thumb, in any conditional statement, I should take care of NAs in that code so that the condition code will work?